# How to remove garbage values from dates extracted with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, date, text-extraction, garbage

Goal: extract dates from medical records (stored in pandas Series, dates are in all possible formats)

For numerical dates I used:

```
str.extractall(r'((?:\b\d{1,2}[/]){1,2}(?:(?:\d{2}\b)|\b\d{4}\b))')
```

Problem:

**Input text1**:

```
"(5/11/85) Crt-1.96, BUN-26; AST/ALT-16/22; Independent
```

**Output1**: `5/11/85` (as wished) but also: `16/22`

**Input text2**:

`[text...] (7/11/77) CBC: 4.9/36/308 Pertinent [...]:`

**Output2**: `7/11/77` (as wished) but also `9/36`

Especially the second case is hard, because transforming it to date returns: September 2036, so, it can't be selected out that way.

`[^-]` makes it even worse.

The dates are everywhere in the text, like:

```
[...] has also taken diet pills (last episode in Feb 1993) but [...]
```

Feb 1993 etc. wasn't a problem.

Comment: Why not just use `^\((\d+/\d+/\d+)\)`?

Comment: All dates are at the beginning of the data?

Comment: Please provide more data. As it stands you could easily use [**`\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?!\d)`**](https://regex101.com/r/4IBhBx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what "all formats" means. In your example you just show 1 format. Could "JAN-02-2016" "01/02/2016" "02/01/2016" all be present? European and US time formats? etc?

In your example, it looks like dates are always at the start of the line and surrounded by parentheses, however, which makes it sort of straightforward.

^((\d+/\d+)).*|^((\d+/\d+/d+)).*

Comment: They aren't always at the start, that would be to easy.
All formats means: 4/3/09, 4/20/09; 6/2008 
also Mar 20th, 2001; 04/20/1973; 04/20/09, Oct 2010, 
Mar. 20, 1997 etc. I think they are all US.
Jan, Feb etc. are extracted separately.

Answer (score 0):

The main rule when you working with regexes is: know your data. You must compose as much accurate regex as you can.

Then I would suggest you to *parse* such crude dates into actual, full-fledged *date objects*. It serves two main goals: first, you filter out negative regex matches; second, now you can cope with your dates in much more convenient, handy way using date object's methods rather than comparing just text strings. For example, you can access date's day, month or year, compare it with desired value, and filter out dates based on such comparison.

For parsing dates I would recommend you to use one of sophisticated date parsing libraries, such as `dateutil` or `dateparser`, which handles a lot of tricky details for you, for free.